# Android: removing elements from list with iterator

Tags: java, android, list, iterator

```
     private void removeLettersFromMakeWords(List<String> a, List<String> b){
     Iterator<String> i = a.iterator();

     for(String s:b)
         while (i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();

            if(o.toString().equals(s)){
                i.remove();
                break;
            }
         }
    }
```

I use an iterator to loop through my list and remove an element from the list if there is a match. 
For example: if `a` = `[a, y, f, z, b]` and `b` = `[a, f]` --> the output will be `a` = [`y, z, b`]

Problem is if `a` = `[a, y, f, z, b]` and `b` = `[f, a]` --> the output will be `a` = [`a, y, z, b`]
and the iterator doesn't remove the [`a`] value in the beginning. Is there a way to reset the iterator so that every time I `break` the iterator starts from the beginning? Or is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: The issue is that you never reset the iterator. You could simply create a new iterator for each string of b. However, I would recommend to simply use `a.removeAll(b)` instead of all that code.

Comment: thanks that is much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "reset" an iterator, but you can just get a new one whenever you want to iterate from the beginning again. Like this:

```
if (o.toString().equals(s)) {
     i.remove();
     i = a.iterator();
     break;
}
```

**Edit**: as @njzk2 says in his comment, there are better (built-in) methods for doing this.

Comment: this is great! and ya the removeAll is much simpler

Comment: @user2456977 Indeed. However, since the subject was "removing elements from list with iterator"... :)